# How to change the size of containers in PKI based applet of a SmartCard?

Tags: authentication, applet, smartcard

I am working with IDprime MD 830 SmartCard, that contains a PKI applet having containers of equal size. I want to change no of containers and their size. How can i do this?

I am new in PKI applets. I have the admin key to login as an administrator role.

I have studied APDU commands but there is no command that can change the size of already existing container

Comment: I would look in the IDprime documentation first. If nothing is there, ask them. There is a chance, however, that the applet does not support different sizes.

Comment: Documentation is not provided with the SmartCard. Thank you for response @guidot.